# How do you mix Line-In Live Recording and soundfiles being played into a skype input stream?

Tags: c#, naudio

So I looked at http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/articles/Skype-Voice-Changer. I started reading at Intercepting Skype Audio.

What I understand is that the most important part is

```
void OnMicServerExecute(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs args)
{
  toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Got " + args.Buffer.Length + " bytes";
  if (outStream != null)
  {
    // give the input audio to the beginning of our audio graph
    bufferStream.SetLatestInBuffer(args.Buffer);
    // process it out through the effects
    outputStream.Read(args.Buffer, 0, args.Buffer.Length);
    // play it back
    outStream.Write(args.Buffer, 0, args.Buffer.Length);
  }
}
```

So you set up a TCPServer you stream the mic-data from skype to. Then you replace the stream with your modified data and give it to outStream, which again is delivered to the other side. So outputStream has to contain my content somehow. This is where the problem comes in. I have my microphone connected with LINE-IN. I want the LINE-IN stream to be mixed with a sound file I am currently playing using

```
void abspielen(string Dateiname, float ZielAmplitude)
{
  Klangwiedergabegeraet = new WaveOutEvent();
  Klangwiedergabegeraet.DeviceNumber = cbAusgabegeraete.SelectedIndex;
  timer1.Enabled = true;
  ISampleProvider StueckchenHalter = null;
  try
  {
    StueckchenHalter = CreateInputStreamS(Dateiname,ZielAmplitude);
  }
  catch (Exception createException)
  {
    MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0}", createException.Message), "Error Loading File");
      return;
  }
  try
  {
    Klangwiedergabegeraet.Init(new SampleToWaveProvider(StueckchenHalter));
  }
  catch (Exception initException)
  {
    MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0}", initException.Message), "Error Initializing Output");
      return;
  }
  Klangwiedergabegeraet.Play();
}
```

and forwarded to Skype.

I have problems wrapping my head around mixers, making something usable out of e.buffer that is being delivered by

```
void waveInStream_DataAvailable(object sender, WaveInEventArgs e)
```

and streaming it. When the server is started and I use no mixer but the wavestream while it's being played at first the volume decreases and it's speed increases. When I hear skype playback it is all slowed down instead.

Please give me a route to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `BufferedWaveProvider`. As you receive data from `WaveIn`, place the received data into the `BufferedWaveProvider`. You can then mix that in with the input from Skype, or replace it entirely.